# Detect and save duplicated rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns in the below format:

```
Id    Year    Month   
123   2021    02
123   2021    02
345   2021    03
345   2021    03
567   2021    04
```

I am trying to detect duplicate rows based on "Id" column and keep both the rows. Hence, in the result it has to be

```
Id    Year    Month   
123   2021    02
123   2021    02
345   2021    03
345   2021    03
```

I am trying this code:

```
df_duplicates = df[df.duplicated('Id')]
```

But it does not yield the expected results. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keep=False`:

```
df[df.duplicated('Id', keep=False)]
```