# Find all the rows in a pandas dataframe where list values repeat in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe which looks something like this where I have already sorted it based on the `Page Count` and the column `Split Parties` contains list of elements

| DocSetID | Duplicate Status | Page Count | split_counterparties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8032866 | Primary | 39 | ['Bass Pro LLC'] |
| 8032866 | Duplicate | 39 | ['Bass Pro LLC'] |
| 8040900 | Primary | 39 | ['Bass Pro LLC'] |
| 8009326 | Primary | 39 | ['Blackrock Inc'] |
| 8014340 | Primary | 39 | ['Booking Holdings Inc'] |
| 8010961 | Primary | 39 | ['Cadence Design Systems Inc'] |
| 8010932 | Primary | 39 | ['Cadence Design Systems Inc'] |
| 8019492 | Primary | . 39 | ['Cartavi LLC'] |

I want only to select the rows where the `Split parties` are repeated. So for example based on these criteria I would get back

- rows containing Bass Pro LLC
- rows containing Cadence Design Systems.

So far I have gotten to sorting the dataframe by Page count and I am really stuck on how to get this further filtering based on similar list elements in successive rows.

I would really appreciate some help or guidance in this regard.

**Edit:** Added more relevant data examples

Comment: Use `count()` and `groupby()`, and return all the rows where the count > 1.

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor of your input?

Comment: added more relevant data above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect and save duplicated rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079961/detect-and-save-duplicated-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It's cool if you found what you were looking for with JLA's answer. A lambda function to detect duplicates, when pandas alreay has it implemented, seriously? :) What in the two upvoted answers does not fit your requirements?

Comment: The two upvoted comments provide a general guidance, with no real solution. I tried those two but found the accepted answer to be the better solution

Comment: Didn't mean the upvoted comments, but the answers. Use of `.duplicated` is objectively the best answer here. lambda function and temporary extra column are reinventing what's already existing. I agree the comment "*Use count() and groupby(), and return all the rows where the count > 1.*" is misguiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `.duplicated`:

```py
mask = df.duplicated(subset="Split parties", keep=False)
print(df.loc[mask, "Doc id"].to_list())
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6]
```

Comment: I see why Andrej's answer might be better to the point: "select" the rows, not "subset" them (upvoted). But why select by "Doc id"? (now called "DocSetID")

Comment: @OCa In the original question they want to "select" rows 1, 2, 3, 6 which corresponded to "Doc id" (so I selected this).

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- The prior sortings that you operated are not required for the method below. You may skip those.
- column dtype does not matter either. Whether it's scalars, arrays or lists of strings, duplicates are found all the same.

*Has a column changed name after an edit? A column 'split_counterparties' exists but not 'Split parties'. I'll assume that's the column you're talking about.*

```py
df[df.duplicated(subset='split_counterparties', keep=False)]

   DocSetID Duplicate Status  Page Count          split_counterparties
0   8032866          Primary          39                [Bass Pro LLC]
1   8032866        Duplicate          39                [Bass Pro LLC]
2   8040900          Primary          39                [Bass Pro LLC]
5   8010961          Primary          39  [Cadence Design Systems Inc]
6   8010932          Primary          39  [Cadence Design Systems Inc]
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be good to show what you've tried so far so we can help you debug your code. Regardless, I believe this will get you there.

```
# You've already sorted the DataFrame by Page Count
df = df.sort_values(by='Page Count')

# Now you can create a new column 'Repeated' to mark rows with repeated split parties
df['Repeated'] = df['Split parties'].apply(lambda x: df[df['Split parties'].apply(lambda y: set(x) == set(y))].shape[0] > 1)

# Finally, filter on 'Repeated' and drop the column
result = df[df['Repeated']]
result = result.drop(columns='Repeated')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wish i could share the data but it is protected information, but I can creat a representative example and share above.

Comment: let me try your suggestion

Comment: added a better data example

Comment: getting this error when trying your suggestion

`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a updated suggestion with a dataframe created from your example data. This runs for me and outputs what I think it is you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'DocSetID': [8032866, 8032866, 8040900, 8009326, 8014340, 8010961, 8010932, 8019492],
        'Duplicate Status': ['Primary', 'Duplicate', 'Primary', 'Primary', 'Primary', 'Primary', 'Primary', 'Primary'],
        'Page Count': [39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
        'split_counterparties': [['Bass Pro LLC'],
                                 ['Bass Pro LLC'],
                                 ['Bass Pro LLC'],
                                 ['Blackrock Inc'],
                                 ['Booking Holdings Inc'],
                                 ['Cadence Design Systems Inc'],
                                 ['Cadence Design Systems Inc'],
                                 ['Cartavi LLC']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# You've already sorted the DataFrame by Page Count
df = df.sort_values(by='Page Count')

# Now you can create a new column 'Repeated' to mark rows with repeated split_counterparties
df['Repeated'] = df['split_counterparties'].apply(lambda x: df[df['split_counterparties'].apply(lambda y: set(x) == set(y))].shape[0] > 1)

# Finally, filter on 'Repeated' and drop the column
result = df[df['Repeated']]
result = result.drop(columns='Repeated')

print(result)
```

Comment: That crafting a lambda function that is redundant with the well known pandas `duplicated` function, would be the preferred answer, strikes me as a little odd.

Comment: This is not a good solution: a nested `.apply` with lambdas instead of using efficient native Pandas methods?